# the most accurate system that can show the positions of planets at my birthday

Tags: planet, solar-system

My birthday : **4 December 1982**

If you have such astronomical calculator **on your computer** please send me the result !

Alternatively if you know an **online** astronomical service for my purpose please link it here ?

I am so curious to discover geometrical proportions between distance and angle of planets at that **date** ...

Comment: I use a simulator called Stellarium for MacOS that I've found to be extremely reliable. Not sure what other platforms it's  available on. What system do you use?

Comment: windows , then may you calculate the date that i mentioned on your Stellarium and show me the result ?

Comment: Personally I would not be inclined to help anyone with what looks like an astrological enquiry.

Comment: Stellarium is available on all OS's.

Comment: Though we as a community have decided to allow *some* resource requests because of their utility to Astronomy, this question does not seem to have much future utility. For this reason, I am closing it as "too broad" as a normal resource request might.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most accurate system is the ephemeris service from Jet Propulsion Laboratory (JPL): http://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/horizons.cgi

Answer (score 2):

If you have a smartphone(android, iPhone, windows phone) there are lots of apps with features like "time travelling" . Location can be set up automatically or manually.
They are all very accurate. One example is google's "Sky Map" , but check other apps too. Hope this helps.